# Who know of usage ionic2 keyboard class?

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic2

I tried use with  [this doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Keyboard/) but script return err "TypeError: _this.keyboard.isOpen is not a function". Ok. i find [this](http://blog.thecodecampus.de/ionic-2-set-focus-input-element/) but in genytools with android 4.4 but i not seen keyboard. Pleace, somebody knows working examples for Keyboard class?

Answer (score 0):

You should use that API to access events from the Ionic Keyboard Plugin. In other words follow the docs for Ionic Native: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/keyboard/. Then use the Keyboard API

Comment: but i trung, my second link uses API, i tried that http://pastebin.com/rNhLjh0V but no result